# Creating a cascading dropdown in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How do I go about creating a cascading drop-down within a list in Office 365 SharePoint?

For instance, if you have a country drop-down and you select United States, you get the 50 states listed. Then if you select Maryland, you get the cities within that state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Info Path form which make very easy for cascading and if you do not want to use Infopath you have to use Jquery CSOM or REST API in the form where you want to use cascading.

Please go through below link for more information :

http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns

Comment: For spservices, your country and states need to be in separate lists.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I started going down the path of using Infopath. I watched some YouTube videos to get where I am at. Now I have three drop-down lists but only the first two are working properly. I need help tying the third to the second one.

Comment: @AlexWeitz you can follow the steps mentioned in the below blog for multiple cascading . [Multiple Cascading](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/05/25/sharepoint-how-to-create-multiple-cascade-drop-downs-using-infopath-2010-aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to implement Cascading Drop down in SharePoint. Step by step article link: [Cascading drop down in SharePoint using REST API](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html)

```js
//Function to filter the values of Drink Types
function loadDrinkTypes(selectedDrink) {
    var drinkTypeListName = "Drink Type";
    var drinkTypeListURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + drinkTypeListName + "')/items?$select=Title,Drink/Title,Drink/Id&$expand=Drink&$filter=Drink/Title eq '" + selectedDrink + "'";
    getReqData(drinkTypeListURL, function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        if (items.length > 0) {
            var optionsAsString = '<option value=""></option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                optionsAsString += "<option value='" + items[i].Title + "'>" + items[i].Title + "</option>";
            }
            $('select[title="Drink Type"]').html(optionsAsString);
        }
    },
        function (data) {
            //alert("Some error occurred in getting Drink Types");
        });
}

//JQuery AJAX to access REST API JSON data
function getReqData(reqUrl, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: reqUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```